# Client with the currently selected authenticator does not support any combination of challenges that will satisfy the CA

Tags: security, nginx, dns

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) to add SSH Certification to my site. However at the moment this method [does not work for the time-being due to a security flaw, so here is the alternate method](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/solution-client-with-the-currently-selected-authenticator-does-not-support-any-combination-of-challenges-that-will-satisfy-the-ca/49983). I'm trying to implement the alternate code-paste: `sudo certbot --authenticator webroot --webroot-path <path to served directory> --installer nginx -d <domain>` however am not sure what to put in `<path to served directory>`.

Is the "path to served directory" the nginx config? Would it look something like this: `etc/nginx/sites-available/<projectname>`?

Comment: same issue, did you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You may have tried this already, but I found this to work, at least until an update is issued:

```
sudo certbot --authenticator standalone --installer nginx -d mydomain.com -d www.mydomain2.com --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --post-hook "service nginx start"
```

Comment: save my life bro

Answer (score 0):

If you are on for debian/ubuntu and running apache this will work for you :

```
    sudo certbot --authenticator standalone --installer apache -d <yourdomain(s)> --pre-hook "apache2ctl stop" --post-hook "apache2ctl start"
```

Source : [Github](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5405)